# Pulling CC data to assign records using Email-to-case

Tags: assignment-rules, email2case

I've been using Email-to-case with success, but I'd love to know if there's any way to pull the name or email of someone who's CC'd on a case into Salesforce.

Right now my assignment rule looks at the subject of an email where users are instructed to type the last name of the rep it should go to.  Obviously this is not ideal.

Any suggestions for improvement?

Thanks!